# Vertical align label

Tags: css, height, vertical-alignment

I have a label that I have styled to look like a button. The problem I am encountering is the text is not vertically aligned when the height is expanded to match the label with more text. I would like both labels to be equal in height with vertically aligned text in the middle. As you can see in the demo, the text alignment is not centered either. Also, how would you add spacing between the two table-cells? I originally have the container to be 100%, with each label being 49% and 1% margin in between the two labels.

http://jsfiddle.net/jasonniebauer/e5dg6/2/

**Updated:**

HTML

```
<div id="table6">
<input type="radio" id="online_paper2" name="tax_forms"/>
<label for="online_paper2">
        Online + Paper
</label>
<input type="radio" id="online_only2" name="tax_forms"/>
<label for="online_only2">
    Online Only
</label>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#table6 {
    width: 15rem;
}

#table6 input[type="radio"] + label {
            box-sizing:border-box;
            padding: 1rem 3rem 1rem 3rem;
            width: 49%;
            display: inline-block;
            color: #BDC3C7;
            background-color: #F2F2F2;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
            cursor: pointer;
            border-radius: 3px;
            margin-bottom: 1rem;
            font-size: 1.125em;
        }

input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vertical align label with padding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20102395/vertical-align-label-with-padding)

Comment: Seems okay here... what browser are you using?

Comment: It works on desktop browser, but check jsFiddle example. This is how it displays on mobile browsers.

Comment: updated here, but no solution still

Answer (score 0):

You can get the desired result by using `display: table` on the wrapper element, and `display: table-cell` on the child elements.

See this updated jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/e5dg6/3/

Comment: how would you add spacing between the two table-cells? i originally have the container to be 100%, with each label being 49% and 1% margin in between.